# Failed to compile on Linux

Tags: parachain

In fact, I was able to compile successfully on MAC, but I had problems compiling on Linux.

```bash
error: failed to run custom build command for `tikv-jemalloc-sys v0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/dev/shm/dorafactory-node/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-8c3a8dc9023b0c9d/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  TARGET=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  NUM_JOBS=4
  OUT_DIR="/dev/shm/dorafactory-node/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-5b25ede0006e4506/out"
  BUILD_DIR="/dev/shm/dorafactory-node/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-5b25ede0006e4506/out/build"
  SRC_DIR="/home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2"
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CC="cc"
  CFLAGS="-O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -Wall"
  JEMALLOC_REPO_DIR="jemalloc"
  running: "sh" "/dev/shm/dorafactory-node/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-5b25ede0006e4506/out/build/configure" "--disable-cxx" "--with-private-namespace=_rjem_" "--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "--prefix=/dev/shm/dorafactory-node/target/release/build/tikv-jemalloc-sys-5b25ede0006e4506/out"
  checking for xsltproc... false
  checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... cc
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
  checking for suffix of executables...
  checking whether we are cross compiling... no
  checking for suffix of object files... o
  checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
  checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
  checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
  checking whether compiler is cray... no
  checking whether compiler supports -std=gnu11... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wall... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wextra... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wshorten-64-to-32... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wsign-compare... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wundef... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Wno-format-zero-length... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -pipe... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -g3... yes
  checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
  checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
  checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
  checking for ANSI C header files... yes
  checking for sys/types.h... yes
  checking for sys/stat.h... yes
  checking for stdlib.h... yes
  checking for string.h... yes
  checking for memory.h... yes
  checking for strings.h... yes
  checking for inttypes.h... yes
  checking for stdint.h... yes
  checking for unistd.h... yes
  checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
  checking size of void *... 8
  checking size of int... 4
  checking size of long... 8
  checking size of long long... 8
  checking size of intmax_t... 8
  checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  checking whether pause instruction is compilable... yes
  checking number of significant virtual address bits... 48
  checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar... no
  checking for ar... ar
  checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-nm... no
  checking for nm... nm
  checking for gawk... gawk
  checking malloc.h usability... yes
  checking malloc.h presence... yes
  checking for malloc.h... yes
  checking whether malloc_usable_size definition can use const argument... no
  checking for library containing log... -lm
  checking whether __attribute__ syntax is compilable... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -fvisibility=hidden... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -fvisibility=hidden... no
  checking whether compiler supports -Werror... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -herror_on_warning... no
  checking whether tls_model attribute is compilable... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Werror... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -herror_on_warning... no
  checking whether alloc_size attribute is compilable... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Werror... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -herror_on_warning... no
  checking whether format(gnu_printf, ...) attribute is compilable... no
  checking whether compiler supports -Werror... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -herror_on_warning... no
  checking whether format(printf, ...) attribute is compilable... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -Werror... yes
  checking whether compiler supports -herror_on_warning... no
  checking whether format(printf, ...) attribute is compilable... yes
  checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
  checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib... no
  checking for ranlib... ranlib
  checking for ld... /usr/bin/ld
  checking for autoconf... false
  checking for memalign... yes
  checking for valloc... yes
  checking for __libc_calloc... yes
  checking for __libc_free... yes
  checking for __libc_malloc... yes
  checking for __libc_memalign... yes
  checking for __libc_realloc... yes
  checking for __libc_valloc... yes
  checking for __posix_memalign... no
  checking whether compiler supports -O3... yes
......
......
  autogen            : 0
  debug              : 0
  stats              : 1
  experimetal_smallocx : 0
  prof               : 0
  prof-libunwind     : 0
  prof-libgcc        : 0
  prof-gcc           : 0
  fill               : 1
  utrace             : 0
  xmalloc            : 0
  log                : 0
  lazy_lock          : 0
  cache-oblivious    : 1
  cxx                : 0
  ===============================================================================
  running: "make" "-j" "4"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)', /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tikv-jemalloc-sys-0.4.3+5.2.1-patched.2/build.rs:334:19
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: What command are you using? Which version of substrate is this? Could you provide the repository?

Comment: What are you doing building down in the /dev/ tree?

Comment: Although this is a useful post for some, its more something you could ask in a developer support channel like substratedevs:matrix.org or make an issue on this page: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem, and there are two cases.

1. Make is not installed. You need to install make
   `sudo apt-get install make -y`

Comment: Thank you! I have the same issue. It's okay after intstall `make` package.

Comment: Ah yes I see now at the end that was what it was trying to run: `running: "make" "-j" "4"`

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to get to the bottom of this might be to:

`git clone https://github.com/tikv/jemallocator.git` and put some println next to `build.rs:334:19` so that you can find out which command it's actually complaining about.

`cargo build` in the `jemalloc-sys` dir should invoke the same error. Once you know what it's really complaining about the fix should be fairly trivial. ( could also consider a PR so that the next person gets a nicer failure)